# Deploying CXF 3.1.7 in WildFly 10

Tags: java, cxf, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am getting the below exception:

> 18:45:51,355 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.apache.cxf.ws.security.sts.provider.SecurityTokenServiceProvider in Module "deployment.Sample.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/ws/security/sts/provider/SecurityTokenServiceProvider (Module "deployment.Sample.war:main" from Service Module Loader): javax/xml/ws/Provider

Logs :

```
18:45:51,365 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Sample.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Sample.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Sample.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/ws/security/sts/provider/SecurityTokenServiceProvider (Module "deployment.Sample.war:main" from Service Module Loader): javax/xml/ws/Provider
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this resource helpful, when solving similar problem to the reported. https://developer.jboss.org/thread/268163
When I applied suggestion made by Reto Hodel (2017-03-07 09:56), that is, "Adding two module dependencies in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml: java.xml.ws.api (which actually contains the Provider interface) and javax.jws.api", the problem has fixed iself.